# jQuery custom event via object not triggered

Tags: jquery, events

I'm having an issue with a custom jQuery event and listening to it via delegation, depending on how the event is triggered. The string event is correctly triggered on both p tags. The jQuery.Event object, however, does only get triggered on the directly bound p tag. I prepared a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/s35bg/

Here's the HTML:

```
<p class="delegation">Via delegation:</p>
<p class="direct">Directly:</p>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    // bind using delegation
    $(document).on('create', 'p.delegation', function (e) {
        if (e.test) {
            $(this).append(' $.Event');
        } else {
            $(this).append(' string');
        }
    });

    // bind directly
    $('p.direct').on('create', function (e) {
        if (e.test) {
            $(this).append(' $.Event');
        } else {
            $(this).append(' string');
        }
    });

    // trigger the event with a string
    $('*').trigger('create');

    // trigger the event with an object
    var event = $.Event('create');
    event.test = true;
    $('*').trigger(event);
});
```

The result is:

```
Via delegation: string
Directly: string $.Event
```

I'm expecting:

```
Via delegation: string $.Event
Directly: string $.Event
```

My question is, why is that? Are my expectations wrong or is jQuery wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there's a clue in that, if you change your trigger from `$('*')` to `$('p')`, the result is: `Via delegation: string $.Event $.Event`, as if the event is being triggered both directly and on the bubble. I admit I'm puzzled, but I wonder about the interaction between `trigger()`, the `'*'` selector, and delegated events.

Comment: @Palpatim which comes as a surprise in my opinion, too.

Answer (score 1):

changed last line.

**before**:

```
var event = $.Event('create');
event.test = true;
$('*').trigger(event);
```

**after**:

```
$('*').trigger({type:'create', test:true});
```

Comment: That definitely works, but it doesn't really answer the question: why does it work while the idiom of declaring a new `Event` object fail? Any pointers?

Comment: Thanks, this might be the workaround I was looking for! Although, as @Palpatim says, this does not really explain the behavior above. Will accept this if the workaround goes well.

Comment: @Palpatim - 'create' event is an event that is not supported by the document seems to be due. The last line of code "$ ('*').trigger ('create')" When running in normal operation, you can see that.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that explanation, since the example in the jQuery Events API documentation (http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) specifically uses an event type called "logged", using the same idiom as @morris4 used. I'm still scratching my head.

Comment: Of course, 'var event = $.Event('create'); event.test = true; $('p.delegation').trigger(event);' is executed. // in jquery event api 'logged' samples '$(document).("logged", "body", function(){});' is not written in the executable.